# How to get value of a key in JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a JSON like this:

```
var arrStages = [                 
    { "strID" : "ID-0001" , "intStageNum" : 1 , "strNumOfDays": 1 }, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0003" , "intStageNum" : 3 , "strNumOfDays": 14}, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0002" , "intStageNum" : 2 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0006" , "intStageNum" : 6 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0004" , "intStageNum" : 4 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0005" , "intStageNum" : 5 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
];
```

How can I get the a specific attribute (let's say I want the strNumOfDays) of each one of them? Do I have to use $.each()?

Comment: Yes! Probably that could be leas possible answer.

Comment: `arrStages.forEach(function(stage) { 
 console.log(stage.strNumOfDays); 
})`

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: please add a wanted result as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to use $.each()?

You'll need *some* kind of looping construct, yes. A `for` loop, for instance, or the features of `Array.prototype`, or in ES2015 (aka "ES6") and later a `for-of` loop, or yes, you could use jQuery's `$.each` or `$.map`. For instance, we can get an array of those values using `arrStages.map`:

```
var days = arrStages.map(function(entry) {
  return entry.strNumOfDays;
});
```

Or in ES2015+:

```
let days = arrStages.map(entry => entry.strNumOfDays);
```

Example (in ES5):

```js
var arrStages = [                 
    { "strID" : "ID-0001" , "intStageNum" : 1 , "strNumOfDays": 1 }, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0003" , "intStageNum" : 3 , "strNumOfDays": 14}, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0002" , "intStageNum" : 2 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0006" , "intStageNum" : 6 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0004" , "intStageNum" : 4 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0005" , "intStageNum" : 5 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
];
var days = arrStages.map(function(entry) {
  return entry.strNumOfDays;
});
console.log(days);
```

[This question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9329446/for-each-over-an-array-in-javascript) cover the wide number of options you have for looping through arrays in JavaScript.

In ES2015 and above, if you don't need an array but you just need to loop through the values, here's what a `for-of` loop would look like:

```
for (let entry of arrStages) {
    // Use entry.strNumOfDays here...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use Javascript's `map()` or `forEach()`, since it's an array.  It's also a little more straightforward than `$.each()`.

```js
var arrStages = [                 
    { "strID" : "ID-0001" , "intStageNum" : 1 , "strNumOfDays": 1 }, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0003" , "intStageNum" : 3 , "strNumOfDays": 14}, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0002" , "intStageNum" : 2 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0006" , "intStageNum" : 6 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0004" , "intStageNum" : 4 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0005" , "intStageNum" : 5 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
];

// map()
var newArray = arrStages.map(function(string) {
  return string.strNumOfDays;
});
console.log(newArray);

// map()
arrStages.forEach(function(string) {
  console.log(string.strNumOfDays);
});

// jQuery each()
$.each(arrStages, function(key) {
  console.log(arrStages[key].strNumOfDays);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: You should also point out that he can use `Array.prototype.forEach()`.

Comment: Sure, added that as well!

Comment: If you're not using the return value from `.map()` you should be using `.forEach()`. (A matter of semantics.)

Answer (score 1):

[`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) could also be used.

It works by receiving two arguments - a function that is called for each iteration over the array and an initial value. In the first iteration, the initial value is passed to the provided function as its first argument (`memo`). The second argument is the currently iterated array element (`curr`). We just push the desired property in `memo` and return `memo`. It needs to be returned because `reduce()` uses the returned value as the `memo` of the next iteration. Basically, the second argument to `reduce()` is an empty array in which we push new values while passing it between iterations. That array is returned with the last iteration and stored in the `days` variable.

```js
var arrStages = [                 
    { "strID" : "ID-0001" , "intStageNum" : 1 , "strNumOfDays": 1 }, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0003" , "intStageNum" : 3 , "strNumOfDays": 14}, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0002" , "intStageNum" : 2 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0006" , "intStageNum" : 6 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0004" , "intStageNum" : 4 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0005" , "intStageNum" : 5 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
];

var days = arrStages.reduce(function (memo, curr) {
  memo.push(curr.strNumOfDays);
  return memo;
}, []);

console.log(days);
```

### Edit

@nnnnnn said `map()` is more straightforward. That's true, but it has a bit less flexibility. For example, if you want to get *only* the values where `strNumOfDays` is not `3`:

```js
var arrStages = [                 
    { "strID" : "ID-0001" , "intStageNum" : 1 , "strNumOfDays": 1 }, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0003" , "intStageNum" : 3 , "strNumOfDays": 14}, 
    { "strID" : "ID-0002" , "intStageNum" : 2 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0006" , "intStageNum" : 6 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0004" , "intStageNum" : 4 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
    { "strID" : "ID-0005" , "intStageNum" : 5 , "strNumOfDays": 3 },
];

var mappedDays = arrStages.map(function (elem) {
  if (elem.strNumOfDays !== 3) {
    return elem.strNumOfDays;
  }
});

var reducedDays = arrStages.reduce(function (memo, curr) {
  if (curr.strNumOfDays !== 3) {
    memo.push(curr.strNumOfDays);
  }
  return memo;
}, []);

console.log("map", mappedDays);
console.log("reduce", reducedDays);
```

Notice that `map()` always saves the returned value. If nothing is returned, it saves `undefined`. With `reduce()`, you control what exactly is being added.

***Disclaimer:** I know this is not required in the question and I'm not saying `reduce()` is better, I just wanted to show its benefits.*

Comment: You *can* do this, but `.map()` is more straightforward.

Comment: True. But if you want to skip some properties, for example, `map()` wouldn't do the job since it always saves the returned value. With `reduce()` you, have more control. Besides, it's still a legitimate solution, so I decided to post it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a closure over the wanted key.

```js
function getValues(key) {
    return function (object) {
        return object[key];
    };
}

var arrStages = [{ strID: "ID-0001" , intStageNum: 1 , strNumOfDays: 1 }, { strID: "ID-0003" , intStageNum: 3 , strNumOfDays: 14}, { strID: "ID-0002" , intStageNum: 2 , strNumOfDays: 3 }, { strID: "ID-0006" , intStageNum: 6 , strNumOfDays: 3 }, { strID: "ID-0004" , intStageNum: 4 , strNumOfDays: 3 }, { strID: "ID-0005" , intStageNum: 5 , strNumOfDays: 3 }];

console.log(arrStages.map(getValues('strNumOfDays')));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: He said he wants to get the property "of each one of them", not just `ID-0003`.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ES6 solution to your problem:

```
arrStages.forEach((arrStage) => {
    console.log(arrStage["strNumOfDays"]);
});
```

I think this is what you wanted.

I Hope it helps.